How can you determine whether your agent's location is global and not in the US within Dialogflow?
Google has issued a statement regarding the removal of US-based endpoints and data storage, necessitating a shift to other regional locations.

However, a challenge arises as the only available region appears to be "Global - Global serving, data-at-rest in US" which still it shows that the Data is in US.

Could someone clarify whether my current location is secure and unaffected by the changes outlined in Google's announcement? I've thoroughly examined all API endpoints and found no references to the US in the URLs. My primary concern now revolves around the location of the agent, and I'm uncertain whether it will be removed once April 16 arrives.
TIA.

Hi @Eggy, Have you checked this documentation of supported regions. As per this, the global region is supported, but the regions started with the US is deprecated. Let me know if this helps you or not.

I already check that part. I tried using 3 different new google accounts (not related to the orig account), when I tried going the the Global server it still show the data-at-rest in US.

As per this documentation, it states that the global location is a special multi-region. Its data centers are spread throughout the world. It is not possible to predict or control exactly which data centers are selected or where they are located.
As far as it is concerned for DialogFlow ES, when it comes to the global region, by default data will be located in the US. i.e., data will be at rest within the US and all the data will be stored in the US based data centers.
In the console only one option is available for the Global region as you mentioned. So, you can use that global region for the endpoints.
However, if you still have any doubts or confusion or need an exact clarification, you can create a new GCP support case if you have a support plan. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Thank you for the answer, I will be waiting on by April 16 if there will be an issue with our Agent Bots under Dialogflow. Currently I cannot say if this is the correct answer as to my account cannot raise ticket to GCP Support. Temporarily we prepared a substitute bot API incase failure of Dialogflow.
